# How to Host A Single Website on Multple Windows Server with same Publice IP Address

Tags: windows-server-2008, hosting, web-hosting

I need to host my website on multiple windows server having same static ip address so if one server

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [Network Load Balancing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732855(v=ws.10).aspx)